Swift Error with existing codebase: Main actor-isolated context may introduce data races
OK, all of a sudden I'm getting warnings (and runtime errors) in code that hasn't changed in quite some time. I believe this has to do with Swift concurrency.
Further details below. All help appreciated greatly. On where to look next.
Using the example code from Apple also shows this issue.

I'm getting errors using the new environment variables to open an existing document: Apple Developer Link
I get this error when I have my swiftui View as being @MainActor:

I get this error without it:

I get this if I set the Task to run on the Main Actor

Run time crash:

And console output on runtime crash:


You should watch all of the new async/await videos. But adding MainActor to the View will likely solve this

Thanks I have watch many of them but will revisit them. I have tried adding @MainActor to the view but to no avail.

We need an MRE to even being to debug this, come up with a small sample and tag me. async/await has strict rules that must be followed. Swift6 is going to rock  the boat in a lot of projects don't feel bad.

@loremipsum - a new project with code from here exhibits the same issue on my system. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/opendocument

The answer was to do as Lorem ipsum suggested to make the parent view @MainActor, but also to pull the code out of the view body and into it's own method and call that async method from a Task call within the view body.
In my code I am declaring the Environment variable within the view as before but have moved the call to it to a function inside the View:
@MainActor struct ExistingProjectButton: View {
    @Environment(\.openDocument) private var openDocument

var body: some View {
...
.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded {
    Task{
        await openExistingDocument(url: buttonURL)
    }
}


func openExistingDocument(url: URL) async{
        do {
            try await openDocument(at: url)
        } catch {
            // Handle error
            print("Error opening: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}


It's .task in SwiftUI not Task. In your case probably something like:
.onGesture {
    count += 1
}
.task(id: count) {

}


Thanks malhal, I'm using Task elsewhere in my app and within a button scenario and still getting the above error. I'm starting to think it's only me/something specific to my system.

Just use .task it wraps Task and cancels it for you which you prob forgot to do
